# How to trigger the Backbone.Router events in Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js, url-routing, backbone-routing

Router in Backbone.js is responsible for routing client-side pages, and connecting them to actions and events based on urls. But how to trigger the url change? I mean if the only way to do this is to enclose the element associated with page routing in `<a>` tag.

Because I have associated the mousedown and mouseup events with the element used for routing, if I put it in `<a>` tag, the mousedown and mouseup events will definitely become invalid as it will have conflict with the click event of `<a>` tag. So is there other ways to make the routing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [`Router#navigate`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate):

> **navigate** `router.navigate(fragment, [options])`
>
> Whenever you reach a point in your application that you'd like to save as a URL, call **navigate** in order to update the URL. If you wish to also call the route function, set the **trigger** option to `true`.

So, if your router is `r` and you want to activate the route for `#/some_route`, then you could:

```
r.navigate('some_route', { trigger: true });
```

Demo (open your console please): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/xkZtB/

Comment: One more question, as I have to access the data in the model to provide the id for my url, such as 'category/:id'. How should I do that?

Comment: @chaonextdoor: You should be able to build the appropriate route as a string and hand it to `navigate`: `r.navigate('category/' + m.get('id'), { trigger: true })`

Comment: Hi man, I have another backbone router problem here： [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346557/backbone-js-router-initialization-doesnt-run-immediately]. Could you help me fix that? Thanks a lot in advance.